# Vertically aligning a submit button and a link with button markup

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

In my MVC4 web application I have two buttons that I want to display next to each other. One is used to POST a form to the server and the other button is used to make a GET request (so basically a link with button markup).

The problem is that they now both display on a different height inline (while they both use the same CSS) for a to me unknown reason.

This is a visual representation in FireFox of the issue:

[image: Button next to each other]

The HTML with Razor looks as follows:

```
<td align="right">
    <!-- LEFT POST BUTTON -->
    @using (Html.BeginForm("SettleWithSalary", "Transaction"))
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        @Html.ValidationSummary()

        @Html.HiddenFor(id => item.UserId)
        @Html.HiddenFor(balance => item.Total)

        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-green">Settle</button>
    }
</td>
<td>| <!--RIGHT GET BUTTON-->
    @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Overview", "Transaction",
            new { id = item.UserId }, new { @class = "btn btn-green" })
</td>
```

And the resulting HTML in the browser like this:

```
<td align="right">
<form action="/Transaction/SettleWithSalary" method="post">
    <input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="***blabla" />
    <div class="validation-summary-valid" data-valmsg-summary="true">
        <ul>
            <li style="display:none"></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <!-- Two hidden fields with lots of information -->                     

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-green">Settle</button>

</form>                
</td>
<td> |

    <a class="btn btn-green" href="/Transaction/Overview/2">Details</a>

</td>
```

What I want is the Settle button to be aligned vertically with the Details button. I tried putting a div with `style="float: none; vertical-align: top` around the button element which does not work. Also putting a `style="position: absolute;"` in the button just displays them on top of each other with the Settle button lower than the Details button. In short, I have no clue how to solve this.

Does anybody here know why they are displayed on different heights and how this can be solved?

**/EDIT As requested:** See [this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pT6r8/1/) for a demonstration.

Comment: Please show a live example (jsfiddle.net) including the formatting you are applying to this.

Comment: The "Settle" button is inside a form-element. Form-elements have a top margin by default, so you'll have to remove that. Or you can set a negative top margin on the button.

Comment: Its impossible to predict solutions, Please include your respective CSS or create a fiddle.

Comment: Fiddle added! @iddo, thanks! I'll look in to that.

Comment: @iddo, Adding a negative value works for margin-top works. When adding `style="margin-top: -10.7px"` to the button it displays approximately at the same height. This 10.7 is a bit of a magic number though. Is is possible to create an exact match?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Different browsers set different default CSS rules in there browsers known as **user agent stylesheet**.

**Here in your code**:

`ul` inside the container `validation-summary-valid` has default **user agent `margin`**. So reset `ul` `margin` to `0`.

```
    .validation-summary-valid ul {
       margin:0;
     }
```

Or you can **reset** the whole user agent styles by including a **reset.css** or a **normalise.css** (Google any of these and find).

Answer (score 0):

Try this..
    `<form>
          <table cellpadding="10" cellspacing="0" border="0">
            <tr>
              <td colspan="2"><input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="***blabla" />
                <div class="validation-summary-valid" data-valmsg-summary="true">
                  <ul>
                    <li style="display:none"></li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
      <!-- Two hidden fields with lots of information --> 
       </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td style="border-right=1px solid #000000;"><button type="submit" class="btn btn-green">Settle</button></td>
              <td><a class="btn btn-green" href="/Transaction/Overview/2">Details</a></td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </form>`